# Python - Typewriter function is not working. Printing whole string after substantial delay

Tags: python, function

I am currently learning Python and I came across a type writer effect. But when I apply the code it does not seem to work. I would appreciate someone to provide their view as to why this does not work please.

When I run the code it does nothing for 3-4 secs then prints the whoe string. I am wanting it to print individual character a time with a small delay before printing the next character.

```
import string

def typewriter_simulator(message):
    for char in message:
        print(char, end='')
        if char in string.punctuation:
            time.sleep(1)
        time.sleep(.03)
    print('')


def print_pause_type(message, delay=1):
    typewriter_simulator(message)
    time.sleep(delay)

print_pause_type("Hello!")
```

Comment: Are you running the code via the terminal, or inside an IDE?

Comment: You need to add `flush=True` to your `print()`, so that it doesn't buffer up output until a full line has been sent.

Comment: You're setting the time to delay between characters to 30 milliseconds which is very fast to notice a delay. Try setting `time.sleep(.03)` > `time.sleep(.3)` and see if you notice it (tested successfully in my jupyter notebook)

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks Jason that worked. What do you mean by "buffer up" and "flush" please?